# Blade templating @extend go up a folder

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Alright so I know about the Blade `@extends` method to enter a folder, but how about leaving one to enter another? How would that be achieved?

For example:

If my `index.blade.php` is in `app/views` and my `master.blade.php` (The layout file) is in `app/views/layouts` I use the `@extends` function like:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

Which results in the application going into the `layouts` folder as expected.

But now, I have the following directory structure;

```
app/
    views/
         errors/
               404.blade.php
         layouts/
                master.blade.php
         index.blade.php
```

Now what I want to do is use `@extends` to have the `404.blade.php` extend the `master.blade.php` but I have no idea as to how to "go up a folder".

**TL:DR** How do I go up one folder in the `@extends` function

Regards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`@extends` is relative to the root of your view directory.

So when you do `@extends('layouts.master')`, it will always be `views/layouts/master.blade.php` no matter the location of the view that is extending it.

In other words, you change nothing and just do:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```